# Is it possible to customize the built in like action story in the stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

With custom actions the stories can be customized. You have a caption and 4 lines of custom text and data. Is this possible for the built in like verb? It would be really nice to be able to use the "like" verb in the timeline and pass along some more information about what's being liked.

In the dashboard it appears the stories for all built actions are not customizable at all.

Answer (score 1):

These stories are customised based on the same Open Graph metatags that are available for all types of Open Graph objects. When using built-in like you can either use one of the [built-in Object types](https://web.archive.org/web/20121006074601/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/) (such as article, blog, book etc.) or you can [create your own custom objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20121018123050/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/) (recipe or run for example).

Either way, you will include the details of this object by including Open Graph meta tags in your HTML such as the below example for a chef:

`<meta property="fb:app_id"           content="YOUR_APP_ID" />   <meta property="og:type"             content="recipebox:recipe" />   <meta property="og:title"            content="Chocolate Chip Cookies" />   <meta property="og:image"            content="http://www.example.com/cookies.png" />    <meta property="og:description"      content="Best Cookies on Earth!" />    <meta property="recipebox:chef" content="http://www.example.com/john_smith"/>`

Once the Like action is published against an object like this, you'll see a story in Newsfeed which represents the OG data provided, such as this:

[image: https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/OGLikes_SocialCookbook_NewsFeed.png]
<sub>(source: [facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/OGLikes_SocialCookbook_NewsFeed.png))</sub>

Full documentation about Built in likes is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/

And Open Graph objects are explained in more detail here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/

Comment: I understand, but custom verbs also have a 4 line template where a limited scripting language can be used to insert other information. So you can include your own set of metadata in the story. For example the "recipebox:chef" property above will never surface in a standard like story, as I understand it. My question and/or request is to be able to customize the like actions in the same way as custom verbs.